# Set cookies only for 2 subdomains (including the one I'm in)

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm using Javascript to set some cookie. I want to set the cookie that will be availiable on the same page I'm in right now and in a subdomain of the website.
for example:

im in : **mysite.com/some-page-here**

and i set cookie:

```
document.cookie = "my_cookie=value;expires=...;domain=.mysite.com;path=/"
```

I'm not sure how to get this cookie set only in this current page : **mysite.com/some-page-here** and in my subdomain **app.mysite.com** only and not be availiable for the rest of the domains.

thank you so much! hope you understand me. (and hope it is possible :))

Comment: Why you are not using hidden feild? just asking if its solve your problem.

Comment: Hey! What do you mean in hidden fields? Maybe it is the solution.

Comment: its like storing your value in html control but its not persistent as cookie. but what you try to achieve is not possible as far i know you can put and read from a same level of your domain but not like setting cookie in x.com/a and read from x.com is not possible.

Comment: It is, what I did above, that Javascript line of code makes the cookie available in all subdomains of mysite. com, I just didn't manage to make the cookie not be seen in some specific subdomains. Thanks mate!